Connect to SQL Server localdb with PowerShell
I wrote a PowerShell script to connect to SQL Server localdb.
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog=master; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=False; User ID=sa; Password=123; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; TrustServerCertificate=True;";
$connection.Open();

The connection doesn't work and shows the following error:

(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
Server/Instance Specified)

I used the same code in .NET 8 and the connection works:
var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog=master; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=False; User ID=sa; Password=123; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; TrustServerCertificate=True;";
connection.Open();

Is something missing in the PowerShell script?
EDIT:
I just found that the Visual Studio Developer Powershell can inded connect to the database, with the same code.
Maybe there's some missing enviroment path that the normal Powershell needs?

Connect with SQL Server Management Studio and check logs in the explorer under Management.  There should be an entry for each connection. I did a google search for "powershell bug sqlclient" and seems others have had similar issue.

Do you have SQL Server Express LocalDB installed? What's the output of sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB when run from a Command Prompt or PowerShell? Is the sa account actually enabled in that particular instance? Do you have the correct sa password for that particular instance?

Just a silly thought, but you're not running your powershell code as admin?

@AlwaysLearning the sqllocaldb command shows the instance data normally. Also the sa user is enabled. Part of the problem is that the exact same connection string works when I do it from a console app with .Net 8, but in powershell don't work.

@siggemannen tried it as admin, but didn't work also

Yeah, my point is that it shouldn't work as admin, because you must run your powershell as same user as localdb belongs to

@siggemannen oh. I understood now. Unfortunately, the same result occurs both as admin or local user

@jdweng I looked in the localdb log, but there's no connection logs arround errors. The powershell doesn't actually find the instance.

The .NET 8 code could should NOT have worked, since Core wants the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet packages instead of System.Data.SqlClient. Using System.Data might imply .NET 4.8. Additionally, I would expect you to need to use Install-Package before this is available.

What instance is being used on the SSMS login Window?  Make sure you connection string is using same instance of server that is in the SSMS login window.  A database can be attached to a server or not attached (connect to a file).  You use Data Source when attached.  You use AttachDbFilename when not attached.  Never use both "Data Source" and AttachDbFilename.

I had a local database which is used for testing ASP.NET Core identity, then I had a test with PowerShell script below and it worked for me.
$connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database={Database_Name};Trusted_Connection=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()


$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.AspNetUsers"
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$adapter.SelectCommand = $command
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset)
$dataset.Tables[0] | Format-Table -AutoSize

$connection.Close()



Could you please have a try? And please correct me if I misunderstood your requirement.

Got the same error as before. What is the encoding of your file? Does it matter to execute it? I tried both ANSI and UTF-8.

Just like you see in my screenshoot, I test it within Windows PowerShell ISE and I didn't set any configuration about encoding.
